# XSS vulnerability while posting data from ASP page to ASP.Net form

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, xss

We have a scenario at my work place where we need to post data from classic ASP page to ASP.Net form. Now this posting have some XSS vulnerabilities. I am just not sure how to resolve the issue. Scenario is classic ASP page post date to ASP.Net form which is a file inside MVC website. Then on page load event of that page, it gets all hidden variables values and create html from in Response and submit the same using frm.submit() JS code. So because of this middle asp.net page, it is open to attacks.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please add some more details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Server.HTMLEncode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to encode the data written to your page if you're worried about XSS.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you rebuild this page at all? So long as you are using just the post method of the form on the classic asp page then you should not need to rebuild the form in .NET you could simply read the post response values.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is pretty old, but I used AntiXSS library provided by Microsoft to prevent XSS.